# In the movie prisoners what does Alex mean he never came

Tags: prisoners

When Alex Jones is imprisoned in the makeshift shower/bath torture area made by Keller Dover. He says during one scene “I’m not Alex.” But then he says “I waited but he never came” “ I just wanted to play but he never came” .... this part confuses me, who is Alex referring to when he says “he never came?” Is this is real dad? Another kid who was kidnapped? If anyone can help explain who is the “he never came” that would be awesome. Thanks